# Unable to connect to multiple WCF services hosted in managed app

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service (service1). I host several instances of this service in managed application (simple .NET applacation). And I have another WCF service (service2) hosted in windows service.
When a run my application all service1 instances connect to service2 and everything goes fine. But when service2 tries to connect to any instance of service1 there is an exception "There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://localhost:8732/TestComponent_6a4009df-cc68-4cd9-9414-16737c734548 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

All services1 instances has unique addresses (see guid in uri) but similar service contracts and binding types. I use netTCP bindings with port sharing turned on.

Any advices?

Note: when I host the only one service1 instance in managed application everything goes fine. I can run several instances of my app and there are no errors too. And only when I hosted several service1 instances in one app I have problems.

There are some code:

Service1 instances creating:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Component = new TestComponent("net.tcp://localhost:8732/TestComponent", Component_OnMessageReceivedEvent);
  Component.JoinServer();
  Component2 = new TestComponent("net.tcp://localhost:8732/TestComponent", Component_OnMessageReceivedEvent);
  //guids is added to addresses in TestComponent constructor
  Component2.JoinServer();
}
```

How it works inside the component:

```
public void JoinServer()
{
  this.StartComponentHosting();

  if (ServerClient != null)
  {
    ServerClient.Close();
    ServerClient = null;
  }

  ServerClient = new ServerClient();
  ServerClient.Open();  //conneting to service2
  ServerClient.JoinComponent(this.ProviderInfo); //calling some method on service2
}

private void StartComponentHosting()
{
  if (ComponentHost != null)
  {
    ComponentHost.Close();
  }

  ComponentHost = new ServiceHost(this);
  var portsharingBinding = new NetTcpBinding("NetTCPBindingConfig") { PortSharingEnabled = true };
  ComponentHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IComponent), portsharingBinding, this.Address);
  ComponentHost.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Component = new TestComponent("net.tcp://localhost:8732/TestComponent", Component_OnMessageReceivedEvent);
  Component.JoinServer();
  Component2 = new TestComponent("net.tcp://localhost:8732/TestComponent", Component_OnMessageReceivedEvent);
  //guids is added to addresses in TestComponent constructor
  Component2.JoinServer();
}
```

From this code section, it seems that all of your service1 instances are using the same port and adress. ASAP, it is not possible to host multiple instances on the same port, if you are not using IIS.

Comment: I use portsharing. It allows using the same port. My server works on 8732 port too. As I wrote when I host only one service1 instance per app and run several apps everything works fine and it works on a single port.